# Break Statement in Gateway Script

Tags: for-loop, apiconnect

I am using Gateway script in api connect. I want to break the 'for loop' when the condition matches. Is it possible to use Break Statement? If not then please suggest alternative approach.

Answer (score 1):

From IBM reference:

When you write programs for GatewayScript, use programming techniques that conform to these specifications:

- ECMAScript 5.1 - the ECMAScript language specification defines the structures and mechanisms of the programming language.
- CommonJS 1.0 - the CommonJS specifications define programming interfaces that address how modules are written to be interoperable among systems.

From the EMACScript 5.1 standard you can use **break** in a **For** statement.

[EMAC5.1 Reference](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.3)

[Gateway programming model and GatewayScript](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS9H2Y_7.2.0/com.ibm.dp.doc/gatewayscript_model.html)